# How to let user input data into observabaleArrays

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to create a grocery list where the user can enter the items and the quantity as well. I've added few items on the list (in the code), but I want the user to use the 'ADD' button to be able to add stuff.

At the moment when the user clicks add, 'new 4' is added.I want this data to be user entered. I'm not sure how to let user input data into observabaleArrays.

I'm fairly new to Knockout.js and I can't find a way around this.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr> Item </tr>
        <tr> Quantity </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:item"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:quantity"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addItem"> ADD </button> 

<script>

    function appViewModel(){
            var self = this;


        self.items = ko.observableArray([
            {
                item: 'Carrot',
                quantity : '1'
            },
            {
                item: 'Milk',
                quantity : '2'
            },
            {
                item: 'Bread',
                quantity : '3'
            }
        ]);

        self.addItem = function(){
            self.items.push({item: 'New', quantity: '4'});
        }   
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function item(item, quantity) {
  var self = this;
  this.item = ko.observable(item);
  this.quantity = ko.observable(quantity)
  
}

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.item = ko.observable('');
  this.quantity = ko.observable('');
  this.items = ko.observableArray([
    new item('carrot', 1),
    new item('milk', 2),
    new item('bread', 3),
  ]);
  this.add = function(){
    self.items.push(new item(self.item(), self.quantity()))
  }
}

var vm = new viewModel();
$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> Item </tr>
    <tr> Quantity </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text:item"></td>
      <td data-bind="text:quantity"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
item: <input data-bind="value: item">
</p>

<p>
 quantity: <input data-bind="value: quantity">
</p>
<button data-bind="click: add">
add
</button>
```